# XPath 1 - Exclusive sibling matching between following-sibling and only the next preceding-sibling (not greedy matching)

Tags: xpath

Banging my head against interior surfaces on this one:

```
<table class="magic">
  <tbody>
    <!-- previous sections here -->

    <!-- uninteresting section example begin -->
    <tr class="head">
      <th colspan="2">Spain</th>
    </tr>
    <!-- ... -->
    <tr class="section-break"></tr>
    <!-- uninteresting section example end -->

    <!-- begin interesting section (position not fixed) -->
    <tr class="head">
      <th colspan="2">United States</th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>  <!-- match here begin (length not fixed) -->
    <tr></tr> 
    <!-- ... -->
    <tr></tr>  <!-- match here end -->
    <tr class="section-break"></tr>
    <!-- end interesting section -->

    <!-- next sections -->
    <!-- ... -->
    <tr class="section-break"></tr>
    <!-- ... -->
    <tr class="section-break"></tr>
    <!-- ... -->
  </tbody>
<table>
```

So far:

```
/table[@class="magic"]/tbody/tr[following-sibling::tr/th[text()="United States"] and preceding-sibling::tr[contains(@class,"section-break")][12345]]

^--- evil magic constant 12345: must not be hard-coded, probably some sort of `count()`constraint  or Kayessian ?
```

But how to find the first `section-break` after `United States`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//table[@class="magic"]//tr[@class="head"  and ./th[contains(., "United States")]]/following-sibling::tr[@class="section-break"][1]
```

Comment: Can replace `./th[contains(., "United States")]` here by `th = "United States"`.